# How to create the equivalent of a SwiftUI stack view spacer programmatically

Tags: swiftui, uikit, uistackview

I'm working on trying to recreate the first [SwiftUI Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views) in code without using SwiftUI. In the example, it mentions using a `Spacer` "to direct the layout to use the full width of the device":

```
VStack {
  Text("Turtle Rock")
  HStack {
    Text("Joshua Tree National Park")
    Spacer()
    Text("California")
  }
}
```

For the `VStack`, `HStack`, and `Text` views, I can easily use `UIStackView` and `UILabel`. But for the `Spacer`, I can't seem to find any equivalent in the standard library (no `UISpacer` or anything like that), which makes me think this is something custom to SwiftUI. In the tutorial, it describes how this `Spacer` works:

> A spacer expands to make its containing view use all of the space of its parent view, instead of having its size defined only by its contents.

So how can I recreate the functionality of this `Spacer` view programmatically? Do I just add a constraint to the UIStackView to make it full width? Or is there a way to add a subview to the UIStackView that makes it behave like it does in SwiftUI?

Comment: You can set  stack view distribution = .equalSpacing

Comment: you can use UILayoutGuide as a container. Is this helpful -: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilayoutguide

Answer (score 15):

I have worked solution using dummy `UIView()` which has set big constant `widthConstraint` using low priority - this ensures UIView will grow as much as possible but will not grow over `superview` constraints since it has lower priority.

Example:

```
let titleLabel = UILabel()
titleLabel.text = "Joshua Tree National Park"

let spacer = UIView()
// maximum width constraint
let spacerWidthConstraint = spacer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: .greatestFiniteMagnitude) // or some very high constant
spacerWidthConstraint.priority = .defaultLow // ensures it will not "overgrow"
spacerWidthConstraint.isActive = true

let descriptionLabel = UILabel()
descriptionLabel.text = "California"

UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [titleLabel, spacer, descriptionLabel])
```

Comment: I haven’t tried this yet but it looks promising. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

### Swift 5

You can create an extension for `UIView` to create a spacer in this way:

```swift
extension UIView {

    static func spacer(size: CGFloat = 10, for layout: NSLayoutConstraint.Axis = .horizontal) -> UIView {
        let spacer = UIView()
        
        if layout == .horizontal {
            spacer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size).isActive = true
        } else {
            spacer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size).isActive = true
        }
        
        return spacer
    }

}
```

After that, you can add your spacer into stacks in this way:

```swift
// ... some code

let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [UIView.spacer(), UILabel(), UIView.spacer(), UILabel(), UIView.spacer()])
stack.axis = .horizontal
stack.distribution = .equalSpacing

// For vertical stacks

let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [UIView.spacer(for: .vertical), UILabel(), UIView.spacer(for: .vertical), UILabel(), UIView.spacer(for: .vertical)])
stack.axis = .vertical
stack.distribution = .equalSpacing
```

I think in this way, you can play with spacer size/layout and stack distribution/alignment to get the desired space.

Answer (score 2):

```swift
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    public static var spacerView: UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.fittingSizeLevel, for: .horizontal)
        view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.fittingSizeLevel, for: .horizontal)
        return view
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```swift
stackView.addArrangedSubview(Self.spacerView)
```

You will have your very own SwiftUI's Spacer() equivalent in UIKit.

Answer (score 1):

A plain `UIView()` can replace a `SwiftUI.Spacer` as long as distribution is set to fill, since it has no set width constraint. I've only tested this vertically. However, you should note the layout performed by `UIStackView` and `SwiftUI.HStack` are not actually the same steps, though the end results may appear similar; something to look into.